# Python not indexing errors as I expected

Tags: python

After getting past one issue (which was answered thanks to @John La Rooy), I encountered a new one. When I type:

```
import subprocess

output = subprocess.check_output('iwconfig', stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
print(output[0])
```

It prints 110, which is definitely not what it should according to what I know. It should be outputting 'b', because that is the first character in the variable output. Any idea why? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> It should be outputting 'b', because that is the first character in the variable output.

Errr... no.

What you are seeing is likely something like `b'foo'`. The "b" is not part of the content, it's part of the type. Specifically the `bytes` type. Which when indexed results in an integer.

```
3>> bytes((110,))
b'n'
3>> bytes((110,))[0]
110
```

Either decode the return value to text, or slice instead of using indexing.

```
3>> b'n'.decode('utf-8')
'n'
3>> b'n'[0:1]
b'n'
```

Comment: I tried output.decode('utf-8') but it didn't work. What am I doing wrong? Sorry, I am new to python (and programming in general)

Comment: Does anybody know of somewhere where I might find more information on this?